# How to adjust the height and the width of jcarousel script?

Tags: jquery, html, css, width, jcarousel

I just love jcarousel script and I am trying to integrate it into my website www.careylist.com.

For the life of me, I simply can't get it to work right. For one thing, I need to be able to adjust the width and the height of the script, but every time I tried to do that by following online self-help it fails. At which point, all the images are listed as a unordered list as follows.

[image]

Here is the script is use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{
    // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};


/**
 * Overwrite for having a carousel with dynamic width.
 */
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 85%;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    height:300px;

}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 2800,
    visible:5,
    circular: true,
    speed: 1100,
    scroll: +1,
    vertical: false,
    circular: true,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
});
</script>
```

If I remove the section that deals with width and the height in the script above, it works but it has its default width and height.

What am I doing wrong?